# Physics based predictive model using Predict

Tags: physics, machine-learning, modeling

### Summary:

The first order response of a block of metal quenching in a fluid (or a cold block heating in a warm environment) is well known.  I am trying to create a physics based predictive model for this phenomena, using `Predict[]` and `GradientBoostedTrees`.  I would like to achieve a higher accuracy if at all possible and learn a *bit* more on choice of `Predict[]` parameters.

## Details:

I am trying to create a "physics based predictive model" for a first order response of a temperature measurement device, using Mathematica's Predict[] function.  Once this model is trained via a data of `{time, Tinit, Tamb, tau}`, I would like to test it's efficacy versus exact/analytical solutions.

$$T(t) = T_{amb} + (T_{init} - T_{amb})e^{-t/\tau}$$

```
Clear[t, T0, t1, \[Tau], Tinit, Tamb, tc, time];
T[t_, T0_, T1_, \[Tau]_] := 
  Module[{Tinit = T0, Tamb = T1, tc = \[Tau], time = t},
   Tamb + (Tinit - Tamb) Exp[-time/tc]];
```

### Preparing inputs:

```
Clear[input, nPoints, output, time, Tinit, Tamb, tc];
nPoints = 1000;
time = ## & @@@ RandomReal[{0, 100}, {nPoints, 1}];(*time in seconds*)
Tinit = ## & @@@ RandomReal[{268, 300}, {nPoints, 1}];(*initial temp, Kelvin*)
Tamb = ## & @@@ RandomReal[{288, 400}, {nPoints, 1}]; (*ambient temp, Kelvin*)
tc = ## & @@@ RandomReal[{1, 20}, {nPoints, 1}];(*time constant of measurement device*)



input = Thread[{time, Tinit, Tamb, tc}];
output = N[#3 + (#2 - #3) Exp[-#1/#4]] & @@@ input;

dataSet = Thread[input -> output];
s = Dimensions[dataSet][[1]];
```

I have had plenty of success with the `GradientBoostedTrees` model and continued to use it here.

### Predictive model:

```
p = Predict[dataSet, 
    Method -> {"GradientBoostedTrees", "BoostingMethod" -> "Gradient",
       "MaxDepth" -> 5, MaxTrainingRounds -> 2}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
```

The choice of hyperparameters such as `MaxDepth` or `MaxTrainingRounds` did not make the greatest of difference.

### Comparison between prediction and exact physics:

First order response for 75 seconds of time:

```
predT = Table[p[{t, 293, 310, 15}], {t, 1, 75, 1}]; (*prediction*)
physT = Table[T[t, 293, 310, 15], {t, 1, 75, 1}]; (*exact*)
```

### Visualization of error between prediction and exact solution:

**How can I ensure that the prediction is far more accurate than the what  is achieved using `Predict[]`**

Does it come down to just choosing better hyperparameters?  I have tried several permutations and combinations, **including letting `Predict[]` decide**.  The prediction is pretty consistent.

Conversely, is there some good resource (besides the Help pages and experiential learning) to help choosing hyperparameters?

Although the prediction is within pretty good, physically, the transients (t=0-30 seconds) and the steady state are inaccurate.  This is a rather simple physical system.

```
ListLogPlot[Abs[physT - predT]*100/physT, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time [s]", "Error"}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 15}}]
Show[{ListPlot[physT, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   FrameLabel -> {"time", "temperature"}, 
   PlotRange -> {All, {293, 315}}], 
  ListPlot[predT, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]}]
```

[image]

The red dotted line is the prediction using gradient boosted decision trees while the blue dotted line is the exact physics solution.

**Update**: Predict with `GaussianProcess` as suggested by a kind commenter, provided a rather high bad (poor quality of prediction) as seen in the error plot below:

[image]

Comment: This seems more like an interpolation sort of problem than a real machine learning problem. You might give the `"GaussianProcess"` method a go, since that's basically a more elaborate form of interpolation.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit So the `GaussianProcess` method, out of the box, gave me a terrible "interpolation".  The error between the prediction and the exact solution was of the order of about 10%.   Have updated the answer with this detail.  So what exactly is the `Predict` function for?  Is it just interpolation?  I can understand that given a dataset, using Neural Networks or such out of the box are interpolation.

Comment: The training data uses time constants in the range `{1, 10}`. The comparison uses a time constant of 15, which is well outside of the training range. Is that intentional?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks for noticing.  I corrected it in my code but didn't change the result by too much.  Will update question shortly.

Comment: In machine learning, it is typically not the tuning of hyperparameters that solves the problem, or even the choice of method. More commonly, it comes down to feeding your algorithms with enough data. In this case, for example, if you up the number of examples to 50,000 and the number of training rounds to 100, you get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VH4Y8.png), which is much better. With even more examples, (and perhaps with a bit of hyperparameter tuning,) I'm sure you can get even better results. By the way, you forgot to define the `T` function.

Comment: @C.E. Thank you for noticing.  I have included the `T` function now.  Is there some way of ensuring that using tens-of-thousands of input->output examples is not as time consuming as it currently is (takes upwards of 10 real seconds, boy do I sound greedy!)?

Comment: @drN Training machine learning algorithms is supposed to take time. Training neural networks for some image processing tasks, for example, can take days on high-end GPUs. The salient feature of these algorithms, though, is that the time it takes to make a prediction does not increase with the number of input-output examples. So, while the time it takes to train the method increases with the number of examples, this is not commonly seen as a problem.

Comment: I suppose you're asking because you want to try more hyperparameters faster. I'm afraid that's not possible to do anything about, a given set of hyperparameters and training data will take a certain amount of time. It is enough, though, to get the hyperparameters approximately right, so your search for hyperparameters can be rough. The reward for making them optimal as opposed to approximately right is usually pretty small.

Comment: @CE  Could you recommend any reading (papers are fine too) on ML or specific ML algorithms for a non computational scientist?  What I have come to realize that ML is a rather deep field.

Comment: @drN I'm afraid not, but I think learning about popular methods like SVM, Gaussian Processes and multi-layer perceptrons (a simple type of neural network) can go a long way. And for unsupervised machine learning, K-means and hierarchical clustering. Machine learning methods are like that, but with varying level of sophistication.

Comment: @drN Unrelated to your question. Can you explain the use of `## & @@@`. I have never seen that construct before. This `RandomReal[{0, 100}, nPoints] generates the same result as ## & @@@ RandomReal[{0, 100}, {nPoints, 1}]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi  The `RandomReal[...]` output is placed in the `##` slot and applies this to the level 1 of the list.  See this also: `ref/Apply` as it probably is far more articulate!